# How does one access the actual arguments to an Emacs Lisp function from the `*Backtrace*`?

Tags: debugging, backtrace

I am trying to debug a problem in some elisp and don't understand how to access the information I want from the Emacs Debugger.

Specifically, my backtrace looks like:

```
⋮
  #f(compiled-function (hover) #<bytecode 0x26f7872a3e8bae1>)(#<hash-table equal 1/1 0x1fe85528cbdf>)
  apply(#f(compiled-function (hover) #<bytecode 0x26f7872a3e8bae1>) #<hash-table equal 1/1 0x1fe85528cbdf>)
  #f(compiled-function (&rest args) #<bytecode 0xe8a92e4d3997328>)(#<hash-table equal 1/1 0x1fe85528cbdf>)
  #f(compiled-function (result) #<bytecode -0xd842d2c46378a2f>)(#<hash-table equal 1/1 0x1fe859656ddf>)
  #f(compiled-function (result) #<bytecode -0x6d44600f4b68ed1>)(#<hash-table equal 1/1 0x1fe859656ddf>)
  funcall(#f(compiled-function (result) #<bytecode -0x6d44600f4b68ed1>) #<hash-table equal 1/1 0x1fe859656ddf>)
⋮
```

and I want to examine those `#<hash-table…>` values.

How do I access those? That is, if I wanted to call `(hash-table-keys #<hash-table…>)`, how would I do that from the `*Backtrace*` buffer?

(At least some of the functions are generated by complicated macros, so I can't just use `Edebug`—at least not easily.)

Comment: I personally have gone bonkers trying to debug stuff that has been compiled, and what I usually do is remove the byte-compiled files, reboot, and try to reproduce the bug without said files.  That way, I can start examining stuff more easily.

Comment: I would recommend simply visiting the library file in question and using `M-x eval-buffer`.

Comment: Your lambda is compiled so the debugger can't step inside it. when it's not compiled, you'll be able to use `e` to get value of the hash table, see Drew's answer.

Answer (score 3):

Load the source file (`*.el`, not `*.elc`) that defines the function you're interested in. E.g., `M-x load-file` or `M-x load-library` (but be sure to specify `.el`).

Then use `M-x debug-on-entry`, to enter the debugger when that function is called. Step through the debugger with `d` (or `c` to skip through a step you're not interested in). Use `e` to evaluate any sexp (e.g. the value of an argument) at any time.

If the function you want has no name then you can, alternatively, insert `(debug)` anywhere in its source code, to create a break point, which will open the debugger at that point.

You can also insert `(debug nil SEXP1 SEXP2...)`, where each `SEXPN` is something you want evaluated and printed when the debugger opens.